# how to populate list from sql server database in asp.net using json and ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ajax, jquery-mobile

i want to populate a list from database i am using jquery mobile , asp.net, C#, and sql server database

i wrote a service to get the data from the database as a dtataset but i couldn't convert the dataset to something json can understand

so this is my service

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static DataSet GetProducts()
    {
        string query = "SELECT [product] ,[img1] ,[descr] FROM [ELQ].[dbo].[products]";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);

        return GetData(cmd);

    }
    private static DataSet GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        string connString = "Data Source=GHOST-PC\\STC;Initial Catalog=ELQ_z;Integrated Security=True";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds);
                    return ds;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is my list

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
                <li><a href="ray.html">
                    <img src="pic/ip5.jpg">
                    Iphone </a></li>
                <li><a href="scott.html">
                    <img src="pic/s2.jpg">
                    S2</a></li>
                <li><a href="todd.html">
                    <img src="pic/s3.jpg">
                    S3</a></li>
                <li><a href="dave.html">
                    <img src="pic/nt2.jpg">
                    note2</a></li>
            </ul>
```

how can i convert this to json and populate the list with ajax

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Sep/03/DataTable-JSON-Serialization-in-JSONNET-and-JavaScriptSerializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used the DTO (data transfer object)  way and here is my code

first i wrote a class product

```
public class product
{
    //[product] ,[img1] ,[descr]
    public string name;
    public string img1;
    public string descr;

}
```

and then i altered the getdata() method to be like this

```
[WebMethod]
    public List<product> getdata()
    {
        List<product> productt = new List<product> {};
        string query = "SELECT [product] ,[img1] ,[descr] FROM [ELQ].[dbo].[products]";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        DataSet ds = GetData(cmd);
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        foreach(DataRow item in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            product pro = new product();
            pro.name = item["product"].ToString();
            pro.img1 = item["img1"].ToString();
            pro.descr = item["descr"].ToString();
            productt.Add(pro);
        }

        return productt; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What API are you using in ASP.Net? Are you using web forms, or mvc or webapi?

If you want to keep your code as above, you will want to create a DTO (data transfer object) class and populate it from your data set. You can then serialize it using Json.Net which you can easily install using NuGet.

Probably a better option is to use WebAPI and Entity Framework. WebAPI will do the serialization for you. It is a great way to create an API that you jQuery Mobile app can access to GET, POST, PUT and Delete data.

I'm sure if you google getting started with WebAPI you will find many getting started tutorials in both print and video form.

Comment: Thanx pilotBob it helped me allot

Comment: Thanks, glad to help. Any change you could mark this as the answer?

Comment: and then you changed it to your own answer. Ok.

Comment: well i didn't want to take credit but i did it for beginners  like me who want a solution with an example, so if u think i shouldn't do that i ll mark your answer as the correct answer because u really deserve it body

Comment: no problem... I'm not that concerned about my rep points. Glad you got a solution that works for you.